# Show $X=\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}:x_{2i-1}<x_{2i+1} \land x_{2(i+1)}<x_{2i}\ \forall \ i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is uncountable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I intend to show that $X=\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}:x_{2i-1}<x_{2i+1}\ \text{and} \ x_{2(i+1)}<x_{2i}\ \forall \ i \in \mathbb{N}\}$, the set of all integer sequences that have increasing odd subsequences and decreasing even subsequences, is uncountable.

*Proof.* Proof by contradiction using Cantor's diagonal argument. We'll show that there's at least one element in $X$ that is not hit by a function $\varphi\colon \mathbb{N}\to X$.

Suppose that $X$ is countable. Then we can enumerate its sequences $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ as:
\begin{align*}
    1\mapsto \varphi(1)&=s_1=(s_{11},s_{12},s_{13},\dots)\\
    2\mapsto \varphi(2)&=s_2=(s_{21},s_{22},s_{23},\dots)\\
    3\mapsto \varphi(3)&=s_3=(s_{31},s_{32},s_{33},\dots)\\
    &\vdots\\
    n\mapsto \varphi(n)&=s_n=(s_{n1},s_{n2},s_{n3},\dots)\\
    &\vdots
\end{align*}

Define $s_n(m) := s_{nm}$. Example: $s_1(2)=s_{12}$.

We now build the sequence $s$, defined inductively by:
\begin{align*}
    &s(1)=s_1(1)+1\\
    &s(2)=s_2(2)-1\\
    &s(2n+1)=\max{(s_{2n+1}(2n+1),s(2n-1))}+1\\
    &s(2n)=\min{(s_{2n}(2n),s(2(n-1))}-1
\end{align*}

We see that although $s\in X$, it is not hit by any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore $\varphi$ is not surjective and $X$ is uncountable.

Is this correct? Any correction or proof-writing tip is obviously appreciated.

Comment: Your argument is both correct and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct, but it would be somewhat simpler to encode a set into $X$ which is already known to uncountable.

Take for example $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, the uncountable space of binary sequences. Define a function $\Omega$ from $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $X$ which sends $(a_1,a_2,a_3\ldots)$ to the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_i=i$ if $i$ is odd, $x_2=0$ and for every $i\geq 1$, $x_{2i+2}=x_{2i}-a_i-1$. Since one can recover $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$ from $\Omega((a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots))$ the function $\Omega$ is injective, and so $X$ must be uncountable as well.